# Orchard: Projection-Query filtering Taxonomy-terms

Tags: orchardcms

I created a Content-Type called Contact (fields like Name, e-mail...).

I also have two Taxonomies:

```
Location (N.Y, Denver, Washington...)
Department(Computers, Hardware, Software...)
```

I included both in my Contact-type

Now I want to find a way how I can add a **parameterized** query to filter by Location AND Department.

I can write a Query with a filter on Location - but cannot find a way to set Location dynamically. (can only pick from list)

Ideally, if the page is http://server.com/Denver the page should list all Departments in Denver - with links

So http://server.com/Denver/Hardware should list all Contacts with the Taxonomy-Terms "Denver" and "Hardware"

Or is there a better way than using Taxonomies and Projections?

Thank you,

Reinhard

Comment: Have you thought of using tokens?

Comment: Please elaborate on the comment you have provided.

Comment: Did you get any further with this?  I'm also trying to do a dynamic query, based on a TaxonomyField of the current content in my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261689/orchard-cms-dynamic-query-based-on-taxonomyfield-of-current-content