# Orchard CMS - dynamic query based on TaxonomyField of current content

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am looking into using Orchard CMS for an upcoming project and have hit a block.  The site need to display articles of various types alongside a list of recent articles of the same type.

To that end I have:

1. Created a custom ContentType called Article which includes a TaxonomyField for ArticleType.
2. Created a custom theme with zones to reproduce the layout the customer requires. (Including RecentArticles.)
3. Created a custom widget layer to show/hide the RecentArticles zone based on the current ContentType.  (I.e. the RecentArticles zone is only populated when we are displaying an Article.)
4. Created a Projection to show recent content of type Article.

I see that I can use the ArticleType taxonomy field to filter the source of the underlying query of part 4.  However I need that filtering to be dynamic based on the ArticleType of the currently displaying content.

Is this possible?  Is there an alternative way to reach the same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "currently displaying content"?

Comment: The article that is currently displayed.  So whichever article type they are looking at they would see a list of recent articles of the same type in a projection at the side. (Excluding the one they are currently reading if possible.)

Comment: I mean, you said you wanted a RecentArticles zone, which presumably will contain articles. How do you know which one is the one "currently displaying"? Also, on what criteria do you want to filter? Articles of the same type as the current one? Why do you want to do that with widgets?

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest Bertrand. 
What the client is looking for is that when a user is reading an article they will see a list alongside it of articles of the same type, a list which won't appear when viewing other content types. So I was hoping to be able to dynamically use the ArticleType TaxonomyField of the article the user is reading to drive a query/projection showing a list of articles of the same type.  I'm not limiting my approach to widgets, that's just what seemed most appropriate in my early investigations of Orchard.  I would be more than happy to hear about other options.

Comment: Build a new part for related contents, and in the driver for that part, create shapes that you dispatch in different zones. This way, the related contents belong to the content, like it should.